# VF Page with standard controller rerender section

Tags: visualforce, rerender, standardcontroller

[image]I am trying to create a VF page with standard controller where first I will choose a value from picklist between 1 to 10 and based on that fields form my object will be displayed. The problem is I dont want to have two save buttons (one for number and one for the fields) can I rerender the fields section onchange of my picklist.

```
<apex:page standardController="RFP_Template__c" >
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="numberofattachments">
        <apex:inputField value="{!RFP_Template__c.Number_Of_Attachments__c}" id="attachments" onchange="noofattachments(this.value);"/><br/>                       
        <apex:commandButton value="Save" reRender="AttachmentNames" action="{!save}"/>
        <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}"/>   
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="AttachmentNames">       
        <apex:inputField value="{!RFP_Template__c.Attachment_1_Name__c}" rendered="{!IF(VALUE(RFP_Template__c.Number_Of_Attachments__c) >= 1 , TRUE , FALSE)}"/> <br/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!RFP_Template__c.Attachment_1__c}" rendered="{!IF(VALUE(RFP_Template__c.Number_Of_Attachments__c) >= 1 , TRUE , FALSE)}"/> <br/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!RFP_Template__c.Attachment_2_Name__c}" rendered="{!IF(VALUE(RFP_Template__c.Number_Of_Attachments__c) >= 2 , TRUE , FALSE)}"/> <br/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!RFP_Template__c.Attachment_2__c}" rendered="{!IF(VALUE(RFP_Template__c.Number_Of_Attachments__c) >= 2 , TRUE , FALSE)}"/> <br/>           
        <apex:commandlink value="Save" action="{!save}" target="_parent" />                       
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:pageBlock>    
</apex:form>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, maybe if you elaborate and add some screenshots. Would be helpful

Comment: i have added an image of my current page
you can see there are two saves, first saves the number of attachments and based on that the below fields are rendered. and again save is present for saving the values in the fields. That I need to change

Comment: Refer this [example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_pages_selectoption.htm?search_text=countries)

Comment: but i am not using any controller

Comment: @AfrozKazi Post your code

Comment: @AfrozKazi put your code on your question area section below or above the attached image

Comment: i have added the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `OutputPanel` and `actionFunction` to achieve this task. Refer below code:

```
<apex:page standardController="RFP_Template__c" >
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock >
    <apex:actionFunction name="noofattachments" reRender="panel"/>
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="numberofattachments">
        <apex:inputField value="{!RFP_Template__c.Number_Of_Attachments__c}" id="attachments" onchange="noofattachments(this.value);"/><br/>                       

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    <apex:outputPanel id="panel">
    <apex:pageBlockSection id="AttachmentNames">       
        <apex:inputField value="{!RFP_Template__c.Attachment_1_Name__c}" rendered="{!IF(VALUE(RFP_Template__c.Number_Of_Attachments__c) >= 1 , TRUE , FALSE)}"/> <br/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!RFP_Template__c.Attachment_1__c}" rendered="{!IF(VALUE(RFP_Template__c.Number_Of_Attachments__c) >= 1 , TRUE , FALSE)}"/> <br/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!RFP_Template__c.Attachment_2_Name__c}" rendered="{!IF(VALUE(RFP_Template__c.Number_Of_Attachments__c) >= 2 , TRUE , FALSE)}"/> <br/>
        <apex:inputField value="{!RFP_Template__c.Attachment_2__c}" rendered="{!IF(VALUE(RFP_Template__c.Number_Of_Attachments__c) >= 2 , TRUE , FALSE)}"/> <br/>           
        <apex:commandlink value="Save" action="{!save}" target="_parent" />                       
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:pageBlock>    
</apex:form>
```

Comment: but I need to eliminate the first save button. ie the save after the picklist

Comment: yes it is working

Comment: there are two issues i am encountering
1. the width of page inline shows hundred precent but is covering only half of the page
2. the labels of my input fields are not showing. I even used label tag.
(P.s. I have used PanelGroups for inputfields )

Comment: @AfrozKazi What are those issues?

Comment: 1. the width of page inline shows hundred precent but is covering only half of the page 2. the labels of my input fields are not showing. I even used label tag. (P.s. I have used PanelGroups for inputfields )

Comment: @AfrozKazi I would suggest you to post it as a new question along with snapshot and code. Because you might have modified some code as well.